# Single word request - describe a research is important

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

For example, we can say "important research ", "foundational research", "meaningful", "influential", "impactive", or "imperative". But those words are either far too common or too weak. What is a better choice?

I remember something like "se***m***ntic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**seminal**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/seminal)

> 2. highly original, influential, and important; highly original and influencing the development of future events

As in:

> a seminal artist; a seminal idea, seminal (work of) research

[etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/seminal):

> Figurative sense of "full of possibilities" is attested from 1630s.

Answer (score 0):

The closest word to your example I can think of is [seminal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seminal), but you might also consider [vital](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vital), [groundbreaking](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/groundbreaking), [critical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/critical), [preeminent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pre-eminent), [prototypical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prototypical), [demiurgic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demiurgic), or [paradigmatic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/paradigmatic?s=t).